# Why can't I delete the vertices and faces in the legs?

Tags: vertices, faces

I wanna redo the legs of my mesh. I extruded them too early. Does anyone know why I can't delete them? I tried using alt+H to make sure everything was unhiden.

[image]

Comment: Blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3690" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3690/)

Comment: What do you mean you can't delete them?  Just select the vertices and press Delete>>Vertices.  It might help to switch to Wireframe in order to select them all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch to vertex select mode:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses guys. I actually tried those things too. I think I just had a lot of extra layers for some reason. I should have just used remove doubles, but it was late and I was tired I guess.